# ubuntu 14.04 login keyboard stuck on english. I want french keyboard

Tags: keyboard, login, lightdm, keyboard-layout

I installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS on a french computer (AZERTY keyboard, see below) 
[image]

but I selected *english keyboard* while installing Ubuntu. Then change my keyboard parameter like this:
[image]

and here is my language setting:
[image]

Then I installed [sougou for linux](http://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/) (it is FCITX, see below).
[image]

Then I restarted Ubuntu, and on login screen => The login keyboard (and onboard as well) are **ENGLISH**. How to change to **FRENCH** ?

Thank you.

Note: my system is in english language but **I want the french keyboard** as soon as the computer boot, especially to login my password with french accent.

Note 2: for those stuck on the login screen because of this, know that you can input special character on login using the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then character hex code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did:
First, I changed `us` for `fr` in this file `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/YOU`, see below

[image]

And then in the Ubunu system settings, I pressed this button "apply system wide" in the **Language** tab.

[image]

And I pressed the same button but in **Regional Formats** tab.

[image]

And after a restart, my keyboard on login (unity-greeter) is french keyboard!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you press the <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> (or <kbd>Super Key</kbd>, depending on how you want to call it) + <kbd>Space bar</kbd> you can change between the languages. To set French as your default keyboard input, go to System Settings > Keyboard > Text input and then select French and use the arrows below to move it to the top position. I use multiple languages too and this is how I manage them.

Comment: thx for your answer. But I already set the keyboard to french (see my edit). The problem is on the LOGIN screen, impossible to change keyboard to french (BUT after login, everything works fine, my keyboard is french). This must be related to lightdm and onboard keyboard....